# ASP.NET page specific configuration

Tags: asp.net, configuration, web-config

Is there any way to make some sections of the web.config file only apply to a single file (or directory, or a group of files, etc.)

Basically I would like to apply the following thing only to a single page in the application, the rest should use the default settings: (it limits the upload size to 32M)

```
<system.web>
  <httpRuntime maxRequestLength="32768" executionTimeout="360"/>
</system.web>
```

The point is that I only want that particular page to accept large files.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You can use:

```
  <location path="UploadPage.aspx">
    <system.web>
      <httpRuntime maxRequestLength="33554432" executionTimeout="360" />
    </system.web>
  </location>
```

More info [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b6x6shw7.aspx).

Comment: Just what I was looking for +1

Answer (score 2):

You can place a web.config file on any directory of your web application, what you define there will only work for that directory and bellow

Answer (score 0):

You can also try it with the [`<location>` tag](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178692.aspx), however I'm not sure you can use it with `<httpRuntime>`.

Answer (score 0):

Yea use the <location path="..."> element to achieve this.
The path might point to a directory as well as a file.
You will need to set allowDefinition="everywhere".